# Vis-Network.js suppress border from showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a simple example for vis-network.js which generates this:

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Network | Basic usage</title>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/vis-network@latest/dist/vis-network.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network@latest/dist/vis-network.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #mynetwork {
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      /*border: 1px solid lightgray;*/
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<p>
  Create a simple network with some nodes and edges.
</p>

<div id="mynetwork"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // create an array with nodes
  var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
    {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
  ]);

  // create an array with edges
  var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 3},
    {from: 1, to: 2},
    {from: 2, to: 4},
    {from: 2, to: 5},
    {from: 3, to: 3}
  ]);

  // create a network
  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };
  var options = {};
  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Now I know I can remove a border from styles and that removes a border around the diagram but when I click to highlight something on diagram the border comes back

[image]

What is the proper way to suppress the "not defined" anywhere border from showing up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a solution in my case ;)

```html
#mynetwork .vis-network:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: You're correct. I accepted my own answer back then but I also found this working.